# Returning information in addition to metric in nagiosplugin

Tags: python, python-3.x, nagios

I have a nagiosplugin check that get the version of a package using salt (because of the network architecture) and then compare it with a version given in argument, using the salt.pkg_version_cmp method.

I'm able to return the result of this check (-1|0|1) in a metric and display the statusline.

But I want to add the actual version of the package in the status line, and I don't know how to return it with nagiosplugin class|function, and not by using a global var.

Here is my nagiosplugin.Resource class:

```
class CheckSaltPkgVersion(nagiosplugin.Resource):
def __init__(self, args):
    self.package = args.package
    self.rule = args.rule
    self.target = args.vm

def salt_pkg_version(self):
    sa = getSaltAdapter()
    version = sa.exec_function([{
        'client': 'local',
        'tgt': self.target,
        'fun': 'pkg.version',
        'arg': [self.package]
    }])
    compare = sa.exec_function([{
        'client': 'local',
        'tgt': self.target,
        'fun': 'pkg.version_cmp',
        'arg': [version['return'][0][self.target], self.rule]
    }])
    # depending of compare and version, mist return smth between 0 and 4
    return compare['return'][0][self.target]

def probe(self):
    """Runs"""
    yield nagiosplugin.Metric(self.package, 
                              self.salt_pkg_version(),
                              context='salt_pkg_version_compare')
```

Here is my nagiosplugin.Summary (basic)

```
class VersionSummary(nagiosplugin.Summary):
def ok(self, results):
    return ("ok")

def problem(self, results):
    return("warning")
```

I would like to have a Summary like this (ignoring the conditional check about Unknown/warning/critical):

```
class VersionSummary(nagiosplugin.Summary):
def ok(self, results):
    return 'the package %s is in version %s' % (results.first_significant.metric.name, version)

def problem(self, results):
    return 'the package %s is in version %s which is less that %s' % (results.first_significant.metric.name, version, rule)
```

I searched, but the only thing I found was this: [nagiosplugin: how to show different fmt_metric based on the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976631/nagiosplugin-how-to-show-different-fmt-metric-based-on-the-value) and he's doing 2 check (the first in main, then the second in the summary to get the information)

It doesn't seem like the Metric class (https://pythonhosted.org/nagiosplugin/api/intermediate.html#module-nagiosplugin.metric) could carry other thing than the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find another solution than to write a new Context :

```
class CheckContext(nagiosplugin.Context):

    def __init__(self, name, rule, critical, fmt_metric=None, result_cls=nagiosplugin.Result):
        super(CheckContext, self).__init__(name, fmt_metric, result_cls)
        self.rule = rule
        self.critical = critical

    def performance(self, metric, ressource):
        return None

    def evaluate(self, metric, resource):
        need_update = self.compare(metric.value)
        if (need_update):
            if (self.critical == 0):
                return self.result_cls(nagiosplugin.Warn, None, metric)
            else:
                return self.result_cls(nagiosplugin.Critical, None, metric)
        else:
            return self.result_cls(nagiosplugin.Ok, None, metric)

    def compare(self,metric):
        metric = re.sub("[^0-9]", '.', metric).split('.')
        rule = re.sub("[^0-9]", '.', self.rule).split('.')
        i = 0
        while (i < len(rule) and int(rule[i]) <= int(metric[i])):
            i+=1
            if (len(metric) <= i):
                metric.append(0)
        return (i < len(rule))
```

It take the version that return the first salt function. The comparison between the two strings is now do in the Compare.

here are the Summary and the main

```
class VersionSummary(nagiosplugin.Summary):


    def __init__(self, rule):
            self.rule = rule;

    def ok(self, results):
        return ("Package = %s, version = %s, rule = %s" % (results.__getitem__(0).metric.name, results.__getitem__(0).metric.value, self.rule))

    def problem(self, results):
        return("Package %s must be in version %s but is in version %s" % (results.__getitem__(0).metric.name, self.rule, results.__getitem__(0).metric.value))





@nagiosplugin.guarded
def main():
    args = parse_args()
    check = nagiosplugin.Check(CheckSaltPkgVersion(args.package, args.vm), 
                                CheckContext('salt_pkg_version_compare',
                                            args.rule, 
                                            args.critical),
                                VersionSummary(args.rule))
    check.main()
```

The rule is send to the summary from the main, and the version in the result. The context evaluate if it's critical/warning/ok and send the result to the summary.